# Angular2 app issue - have to exec the function twice, to force the changes to appear

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts, plotly

First take a look at my plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/5x76J6i0rm5mmDRDO9QP

Open console and try to click and drag the axes. When you click and move the axis, following function is going to be executed:

```
plot.on('plotly_relayout', () => {
  console.log('relayouted');  
  this.someVar = false;
});
```

And as you will be able to see in the console, it logs the `relayouted` message, but the `someVar` is **still** not changed.

But (**and here comes the weird, unexpected part**) - if you click the chart once again (you don't have even to drag it) `someVar` will be finally changed into false. (as I want it to be)

**My problem is** that I want to change the `someVar` value immediately after the function executes.

It's weird, because the console.log is being logged immediately when the chart is relayouted, but it doesnt happen with the variable.

**Why have I to execute the function twice, to force the changes to appear** ?

Thank you.

**EDIT1**:  If you try to console.log that variable:

```
plot.on('plotly_relayout', () => {
  console.log('relayouted');  
  this.someVar = false;
  console.log(this.someVar);
});
```

It will log `false` in first execution. So it will be some kind of a paradox, because the variable is false, but in the view its being displayed as true! Weird...

Comment: the construction didn't get its destination, you need to force external powers to complete the operation.

Comment: @RomanC Can you give me more details or post a whole answer? By the way, should I use the emitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are listening to external libraries events you must be sure that inside of the events you are running inside of your angular context.

Try with this:

import NgZone from @angular/core

Then add `public zone: NgZone` to your constructor and finally replace your code to the next one.

```
 let plot = document.getElementById('plotly');
    plot.on('plotly_relayout', () => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        console.log('relayouted');  
        this.someVar = !this.someVar;  
      }); 
    });
```

Here's your plunker with these changes: https://plnkr.co/edit/Zqvxpv5tyQ0AIIK7Iapw?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much my dear friend. Have a great day!